# BlazorWorker vs SpawnDev.BlazorJS.WebWorkers - What are the differences

Tags: .net, multithreading, blazor, webassembly, web-worker

I have today been studying the use of Web Workers in Blazor WASM applications and stumbled upon these two, very similar, NuGet packages which enables this:

https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorWorker

https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS (SpawnDev.BlazorJS.WebWorkers part)

Does anyone have any experience in these? Are there any notable differences? I tried both out myself and they seemed to work very well. There are differences of course in how the services are registered and run and such, but I find that being a matter of preference. Are there, to you, any notable difference which would make you choose one over the other?

Personally I like with BlazorWorker the fact that I don't have to register too many new services and don't have to replace the original blazor build app call. On the other hand I like the ways of BlazorJS more when I get the WebWorkerService injected to my own service and keep the logic there rather than in the razor components, and I get to register my own service to the regular DI service container.